# What is the most effective way to use Plasma Cutter

Tags: dead-space

I started playing Dead Space and like the "Cut off the Limbs" idea.  I only have the Plasma Cutter and judging by [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4220/42984) it is fairly important.

While playing, I noticed I could change the orientation between vertical and horizontal (not sure if future weapons will have this as well).  Which of these is more effective?  I've been keeping it horizontal to blast both legs at once, but is this the easiest way to kill enemies?  Perhaps I am missing a more effective vertical-oriented strategy.

I'm mostly worried about the fact that games like this tend to have things hiding around corners and creeping up behind you.  If horizontal/vertical it more effective, then I can default to that so I don't have an extra step when I get surprise ambushes.

Comment: To be honest they are both pretty effective. Depends how many blasts it will take (based on your damage). You only need to take out ONE leg to bring them down. Best strategy for easy kills while saving ammo is to just blow of their spike, grab if with telekenis and impale them with it. You'll find yourself changing the orientation several times in combat, is just the nature of the game. I found myself using it vertical more on the legs, more bullets into one leg. But since spikes only take one shot going horizonal gives you a better chance to land a hit on a skinny target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cutting off limbs works best by firing at the joints. If you're aiming for the shoulder, shoot vertically. If you're aiming for the legs, shoot horizontally.

And no, most other weapons don't have the horizontal/vertical thing; each "weapon" (using the term loosely because most of them are essentially jury-rigged or repurposed industrial tools; Isaac is an engineer, after all) has different alt mods.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the plasma cutter is a useful weapon when upgraded if you use it often enough, upgrade it and then switch to ALT shot and you can get a fairly quick kill.